# How to pass closure to dyn trait object

Tags: rust, callback, closures, vtable, dynamic-dispatch

I want a dyn reference to a trait object, on which I have a method, taking a closure as argument:

```rust
trait DynTrait {
    fn dyn_method(&mut self, closure: impl FnMut(&str) + 'static);
}

// ...

let dyn_object: &mut dyn DynTrait = ...;
```

The closure can live longer than the call to `dyn_method`, so it will be stored as some form of `Box`/`Rc`/... .

This example does not compile with error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `DynTrait` cannot be made into an object
```

which makes sense, since `impl` is just syntactic sugar for a generic function and a trait with a generic function cannot be made into an object.

One way to solve that is to replace `impl` with `&dyn` (The user has to specify `&mut` now):

```rust
trait DynTrait {
    fn dyn_method(&mut self, closure: &mut (dyn FnMut(&str) + 'static));
}
```

But in this case, we don't get ownership of the closure and we can't make it into a `Box`/`Rc`/... . We could make the `&dyn` ref `'static`, but this defeats the whole purpose of a closure and we could just use a function pointer.

The other way is to pass in a `Box`/`Rc`/... directly:

```rust
trait DynTrait {
    fn dyn_method(&mut self, closure: Box<dyn FnMut(&str) + 'static>);
}
```

Which works fine, but now the implementation detail leaks to the user and makes it more verbose for him, because he always has to pass the closure to `Box::new()`. Also, sometimes Rust has trouble automatically inferring the type of the Closures arguments, which makes it even more verbose to the user.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f053ea1afdf22bc61e083a0925aba64c)

Comment: Traits with functions that take type parameters [are not object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). Remember that for trait objects the compiler needs to emit a virtual method table for each type, which doesn't really work for a inifinte family of methods parametrized by a type. You can use function pointers instead of `impl Fn(...)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes I know this, this is where `error[E0038]` originates from. I am hoping for a solution where I can pass an owned dyn reference (like `Box`) into the method, without introducing too much verbosity for the user. Maybe with some sort of a generic shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around the issue by defining the trait like in your last example with a `Box<dyn Fn()>` as a parameter and then add an extension trait that implements the method with your original syntax to everything that implements `DynTrait`:

```rust
trait DynTrait {
    fn dyn_method_boxed(&mut self, closure: Box<dyn FnMut(&str) + 'static>);
}

trait DynTraitExt {
    fn dyn_method(&mut self, closure: impl FnMut(&str) + 'static);
}

impl<T: ?Sized + DynTrait> DynTraitExt for T {
    fn dyn_method(&mut self, closure: impl FnMut(&str) + 'static) {
        self.dyn_method_boxed(Box::new(closure))
    }
}
```

I've renamed the method that takes a `Box` since otherwise it's name clashes with the on from the extension trait.

This approach also let's the user pass in their `Box<dyn Fn()>` directly if they already have it.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=609b182965d425e3457af85fc6814bb7)